# Sort Large amount of files into equally sized folders (windows)

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, file-management, sorting, vbscript

I have about 15000 zip files with a total size of just over 10 gb that need to be sorted into folders that should not exceed 200 mb.
(none of the files are larger than 40 mb and most of them sub 1mb)

Right now they are all in one folder and the naming convention (if that is required) is
CON-XXXXX.zip  (where xxxxx is a number between 00001 and 15000)

Any great ideas for a bat/vbs or something that would create the folders required (name is not important) and move or copy the files to them?

Help would be highly appreciated!
I don't see how it could be done because I am not aware of a way to "track" the size of a folder so that when it comes close to 200 mb the script goes and creates a new one.
Then again I don't know a lot about scripting.

Comment: [`datapacker`](https://github.com/jgoerzen/datapacker/wiki), but I'm not sure if (or how easily) one can run it directly in Windows. [Available in Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/datapacker.1.html), so maybe you can use it in WSL?

Comment: I know, but I am not going to be able to install ubuntu on a work computer :(.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample batch script for you.

It will create folders in the pattern Folder1,Folder2 etc. You have to replace "Filepath" in the second line with the path where .zip files are.

**The code (TESTED)**

```
@echo off
pushd "Filepath"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set fn=1
for %%a in (*.zip) do (
  if not exist "Folder!fn!" md "Folder!fn!"
  for %%b in ("%__cd__%Folder!fn!") do if "%%~zb" gtr "209715200" (
    set /a fn=!fn!+1
    md "Folder!fn!"
  )
  move "%%~fa" "Folder!fn!\"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Response!
It does work, but it creates folders with an average size of 3mb. It takes a maximum of 4 zip files and then it creates a new folder. So it would create thousands rather than around 100 folders.

I don't get this part of the Code:
"%%~zb" gtr "209715200"
What is %%~zb and 209715200? I assume the number is folder size but in what format Bits or bytes?

Comment: %%~zb is the size of file in bytes and the huge number is 200 mb in bytes. Maybe some zips are too long.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't have a single folder that exceeds 5 Mb in my test batch. I have also tried to run it with 20971520000  (two extra 0) so for 20gb. Still it creates a new folder almost right away. 4 Files max with a total folder size between of 0,2-5 mb

Answer (score 0):

## Solution in Groovy.

This script should be platform independent, in case you ever need to run it on a non-Windows system.

### Setup & file collection

```
def archiveRoot     = './test/backups'
def destinationRoot = archiveRoot

def maxDirSize = 200 * 1024 * 1024
def dirSize    = maxDirSize + 1     // Size of current sub-dir
def dirNum     = 1                  // Sequence No. of next sub-dir
String dirName = ""                 // Name of current sub-dir

zipFiles = new AntBuilder().fileScanner {
  fileset( dir: archiveRoot ) {
    include name: "*.zip"
  }
}
```

The `zipFiles` variables is now a list of every zip file that needs to be moved.

### Move files, creating sub-folders

The file size logic is the only non-trivial part. AntBuilder will move the files, and create the directories if they don't exist.

```
zipFiles.each { file ->
  println '-' * 45

  def newDirSize = dirSize + file.size()
  printf '%10s, size: %s dirSize: %s, would be: %s\n',
    file.name, sizeInMeg( file.size() ),
    sizeInMeg( dirSize ), sizeInMeg( newDirSize )

  if ( newDirSize >= maxDirSize ) {
    dirName = "subDir_${dirNum++}"
    println '=' * 45
    dirSize = 0
  }

  dirSize += file.size()
  new AntBuilder().move(
    file:  file.absolutePath,
    todir: "${destinationRoot}/${dirName}"
  )
  println "new size: ${sizeInMeg(dirSize)}"
}

String sizeInMeg( size ) {
  sprintf '%2.2f', size / 1024 / 1024
}
```

## Example output

When running with these files:

```
28/07/2020  12:28    <DIR>          .
28/07/2020  12:28    <DIR>          ..
18/08/2016  18:06        45,908,522 0001.zip
06/12/2018  07:35       110,335,437 0002.zip
27/08/2016  04:54        87,199,956 0003.zip
05/12/2018  02:40       127,576,284 0004.zip
01/08/2016  01:24       126,012,971 0005.zip
              5 File(s)    497,033,170 bytes
              2 Dir(s)  27,829,731,328 bytes free
```

These files are much larger than yours, tehy're just a bunch of files I had to hand.

The resulting terminal output is:

```
---------------------------------------------
  0001.zip, size: 43.78 dirSize: 200.00, would be: 243.78
=============================================
     [move] Moving 1 file to c:\test\backups\subDir_1
new size: 43.78
---------------------------------------------
  0002.zip, size: 105.22 dirSize: 43.78, would be: 149.01
     [move] Moving 1 file to c:\test\backups\subDir_1
new size: 149.01
---------------------------------------------
  0003.zip, size: 83.16 dirSize: 149.01, would be: 232.17
=============================================
     [move] Moving 1 file to c:\test\backups\subDir_2
new size: 83.16
---------------------------------------------
  0004.zip, size: 121.67 dirSize: 83.16, would be: 204.83
=============================================
     [move] Moving 1 file to c:\test\backups\subDir_3
new size: 121.67
---------------------------------------------
  0005.zip, size: 120.18 dirSize: 121.67, would be: 241.84
=============================================
     [move] Moving 1 file to c:\test\backups\subDir_4
new size: 120.18
```

Two files are moved into the first sub-directory. The remaining three files are quite big, so each get their own sub-directory. With significantly smaller files, as you have, almost all directories will have multiple files. The final directory may end up with a single file.

### Running in a real environment

With so many files to scan you'll probably want to delete all the `println` lines. Then you'll just see the list of files being moved, with the destination. i.e. 1 line per file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off & title <nul 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 0a && cd /d "%~dp0" & title .\%~nx0

:next
set "_zOk=." && set _dir=<nul 
set /a "_cnt+=1+0, _sz_lmt=209715200"
if not exist *.zip endlocal && goto=:EOF 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /b /o:s *.zip')do (
     call :^) %%~zi 0000 "%%~fi" !_cnt! && echo\
     2>nul cd /d "%~dp0!_dir!" && cd.. || mkdir "%~dp0!_dir!"
     if not !_sz_lmt! gtr %%~zi move "%%~fi" "!_dir!\" >nul && echo\ Moved: "%%~fj" ".\!_dir!"
     set /a "_sz_lmt-=%%~zi" && echo\Folder: "%~dp0!_dir!"
     
     :loop
     for /f tokens^=* %%j in ('dir /b /o:-s *.zip')do for /f %%K in ('
         set /a !_sz_lmt!-%%~zj')do set "_szj=%%~K" && if not !_szj! leq -1 (
         move "%%~fj" "!_dir!\" >nul && set /a "_sz_lmt=!_szj!" && echo\ Moved: "%%~fj" ".\!_dir!"
        )
     call :^] "%~dp0!_dir!" && goto=:next
    )
   
:^)
set "_lst=%~1" && set "_dir=00%~4" || endlocal && goto=:EOF
set "_lst_=%~3!_lst!" && call set "_dir=Zip_!_dir:~-3!" & exit /b 

:^]
for /f tokens^=3 %%i in ('dir "%~1\*"^|findstr.exe ",.*bytes"
')do set "_zf=%%~i" && call set /a "_zf=!_zf:,=!/1024/1024" && (
cmd.exe /v:on /c "echo\Folder: "%~1\" Size: !_zf!MB" && exit /b )
```

---

Basically, this using one for loop to get the 1º bigger file and 2 loops to get other smaller files to sum until 200 MB or approximate, add one counter to create the folders Zip_001-Zip_xxx

---

- Outputs from my folder =  3.8 GB

```
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_001"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0084.zip" ".\Zip_001"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0089.zip" ".\Zip_001"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0086.zip" ".\Zip_001"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_001\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_002"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0013.zip" ".\Zip_002"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0030.zip" ".\Zip_002"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0115.zip" ".\Zip_002"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_002\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_003"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0140.zip" ".\Zip_003"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0108.zip" ".\Zip_003"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0051.zip" ".\Zip_003"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_003\" Size: 187MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_004"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0058.zip" ".\Zip_004"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0057.zip" ".\Zip_004"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0075.zip" ".\Zip_004"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_004\" Size: 188MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_005"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0056.zip" ".\Zip_005"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0035.zip" ".\Zip_005"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0036.zip" ".\Zip_005"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_005\" Size: 189MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_006"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0055.zip" ".\Zip_006"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0059.zip" ".\Zip_006"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0110.zip" ".\Zip_006"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0135.zip" ".\Zip_006"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_006\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_007"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0049.zip" ".\Zip_007"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0052.zip" ".\Zip_007"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0062.zip" ".\Zip_007"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0070.zip" ".\Zip_007"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_007\" Size: 190MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_008"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0011.zip" ".\Zip_008"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0074.zip" ".\Zip_008"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0069.zip" ".\Zip_008"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0100.zip" ".\Zip_008"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0077.zip" ".\Zip_008"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_008\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_009"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0155.zip" ".\Zip_009"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0119.zip" ".\Zip_009"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0032.zip" ".\Zip_009"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0060.zip" ".\Zip_009"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0085.zip" ".\Zip_009"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_009\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_010"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0083.zip" ".\Zip_010"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0173.zip" ".\Zip_010"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0017.zip" ".\Zip_010"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0050.zip" ".\Zip_010"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0158.zip" ".\Zip_010"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0079.zip" ".\Zip_010"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_010\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_011"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0107.zip" ".\Zip_011"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0001.zip" ".\Zip_011"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0008.zip" ".\Zip_011"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0031.zip" ".\Zip_011"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0167.zip" ".\Zip_011"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0144.zip" ".\Zip_011"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_011\" Size: 186MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_012"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0104.zip" ".\Zip_012"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0065.zip" ".\Zip_012"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0118.zip" ".\Zip_012"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0142.zip" ".\Zip_012"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0143.zip" ".\Zip_012"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0102.zip" ".\Zip_012"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0149.zip" ".\Zip_012"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_012\" Size: 184MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0148.zip" ".\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0117.zip" ".\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0145.zip" ".\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0087.zip" ".\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0114.zip" ".\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0116.zip" ".\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0127.zip" ".\Zip_013"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0103.zip" ".\Zip_013"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_013\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0076.zip" ".\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0162.zip" ".\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0111.zip" ".\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0007.zip" ".\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0006.zip" ".\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0129.zip" ".\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0067.zip" ".\Zip_014"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0109.zip" ".\Zip_014"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_014\" Size: 186MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0016.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0113.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0147.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0150.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0019.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0018.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0160.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0136.zip" ".\Zip_015"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0038.zip" ".\Zip_015"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_015\" Size: 190MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0028.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0005.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0168.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0138.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0009.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0010.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0088.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0161.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0093.zip" ".\Zip_016"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0066.zip" ".\Zip_016"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_016\" Size: 187MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0166.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0152.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0151.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0043.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0153.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0082.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0081.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0096.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0171.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0163.zip" ".\Zip_017"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0097.zip" ".\Zip_017"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_017\" Size: 186MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0098.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0063.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0080.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0053.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0061.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0094.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0095.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0106.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0159.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0172.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0090.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0078.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0120.zip" ".\Zip_018"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0073.zip" ".\Zip_018"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_018\" Size: 191MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0137.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0002.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0037.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0020.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0027.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0004.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0124.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0123.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0122.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0125.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0164.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0126.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0112.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0146.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0025.zip" ".\Zip_019"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0024.zip" ".\Zip_019"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_019\" Size: 187MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0046.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0048.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0047.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0045.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0044.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0033.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0068.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0026.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0141.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0022.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0021.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0023.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0099.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0133.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0157.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0034.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0165.zip" ".\Zip_020"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0029.zip" ".\Zip_020"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_020\" Size: 185MB 

Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0064.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0042.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0121.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0003.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0041.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0092.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0101.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0154.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0169.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0170.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0040.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0134.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0130.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0131.zip" ".\Zip_021"
 Moved: "F:\zip_test\0132.zip" ".\Zip_021"
Folder: "F:\zip_test\Zip_021\" Size: 128MB
```

---

- Relevant note:

**Obs.: 1** You need/want to test this first, I suggest using another folder less than 1 GB (total) files to check if work, or needs some adjusting.

**Obs.: 2** Keep in mind that windows still working to doing a lot of things in the background too, and will "refresh" these files and folders, from time to time, pay attention for preventing possible errors (see the message below), run this bat without Windows explorer has of your zip folder opened

**Obs.: 3** Read carefully **Obs.: 1** and **Obs.: 2** more one time before trying to test this to prevent the following message:

> ***The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.***

---