# Batch to rar files based on total size

Tags: batch, zip

Looking for a batch script that allows to get files from a folder (`.\source`) and create a `.rar` file on other folder (`.\target`), with those files, but with a maximum given size of the all files inside the `.rar`.

I already archived, moving files across the folders and/or creating a `.rar` file with all source files.

The issue is colleting a variable number of files to reach the given (input option) maximum size of the aggregate file.

Found this answer ([splitting in `.\folders`, instead of `.zip`](https://superuser.com/questions/1572262/sort-large-amount-of-files-into-equally-sized-folders-windows) files) answer by [@lo-ol](https://superuser.com/users/969781/io-oi):

```bash
@echo off & title <nul 
    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 0a && cd /d "%~dp0" & title .\%~nx0

:next
set "_zOk=." && set _dir=<nul 
set /a "_cnt+=1+0, _sz_lmt=209715200"
if not exist *.zip endlocal && goto=:EOF 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /b /o:s *.zip')do (
     call :^) %%~zi 0000 "%%~fi" !_cnt! && echo\
     2>nul cd /d "%~dp0!_dir!" && cd.. || mkdir "%~dp0!_dir!"
     if not !_sz_lmt! gtr %%~zi move "%%~fi" "!_dir!\" >nul && echo\ Moved: "%%~fj" ".\!_dir!"
     set /a "_sz_lmt-=%%~zi" && echo\Folder: "%~dp0!_dir!"
     
     :loop
     for /f tokens^=* %%j in ('dir /b /o:-s *.zip')do for /f %%K in ('
         set /a !_sz_lmt!-%%~zj')do set "_szj=%%~K" && if not !_szj! leq -1 (
         move "%%~fj" "!_dir!\" >nul && set /a "_sz_lmt=!_szj!" && echo\ Moved: "%%~fj" ".\!_dir!"
        )
     call %:^] "%~dp0!_dir!" && goto=:next
    )
   
%:^)
set "_lst=%~1" && set "_dir=00%~4" || endlocal && goto=:EOF
set "_lst_=%~3!_lst!" && call set "_dir=Zip_!_dir:~-3!" & exit /b 

%:^]
for /f tokens^=3 %%i in ('dir "%~1\*"^|findstr.exe ",.*bytes"
')do set "_zf=%%~i" && call set /a "_zf=!_zf:,=!/1024/1024" && (
cmd.exe /v:on /c "echo\Folder: "%~1\" Size: !_zf!MB" && exit /b )
```

But could not figure out how reverse it to `.zip` files.

EDIT2 (revised clarification):

Have a folder (.\source) with multiple (lets say 100 files) .CSV files (source_file), with variable sizes ranging from (approx.) from 500kb to +50Mb, with a "twin" flag file - small size (below around 100kb) and small change in name (source_file_flag).

Intend to:

1. select a given quantity of files (source_file + source_file_flag) to reach a given total Mb size of files - currently can select a given quantity (n) of files
2. agregate the "source_file" from #1, into a into a single .CSV file in to .\target as pack_xx.csv ( xx being a increasing number)
3. list the packed "source_file" in a pack_xxx_list.txt in to .\target
4. add the "source_file" and respective "source_file_flag" form #1 to a rar file in to .\targetfile as Pack_xx.rar
5. delete those temporary files from #1 and #2 from the .\temp folder

below code of what already archived: allow to select a given quantity of files (n) and execute all the tasks, and re-run the batch script until no files are available

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    
set "_source_folder=D:\source"

REM Files in folder D:\source
REM ------------------------------------------
REM 1000-source-file.csv        (main file)
REM 1000-source-file-flag.csv   (flag file)
REM 1001-source-file.csv        (main file)
REM 1001-source-file-flag.csv   (flag file)
REM ...

set "_target_folder=D:\target"
set "_temp_folder=D:\temp"

REM ===============================================================================
REM TASK 1 - select files from source
REM ===============================================================================

::: currently is copy a given number of files (_SrcMax) the "_temp_folder", 
::: objective is  to copy a given amount/size (Mb) of files, so each package as around the same size

set "_DataLoc=%_temp_folder%"
Set "_HoldLoc=%_source_folder%"

for /F %%a in ('dir /b "%_DataLoc%\*source-file.csv" ^| find /v /c ""
    ') do if %%~a GEQ 60 (goto work) else (goto FMove)

:FMove
echo Gather Top 40 files
::: maximum number of files to copy
set "_Src_count=0"
 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /o-d /b "%_HoldLoc%"\*source-file*.csv"') do (
     set /A "_Src_count+=1"
     if !_Src_count! LEQ 40 move /y "%_HoldLoc!\%%~a" "%_DataLoc%"
    )

REM ===============================================================================
REM TASK 2 - create agregated CSV from selected files in TASK 1 (only "main" files)
REM ===============================================================================

::: create temporary agregated CSV file 
copy "%_temp_folder%\*source-file.csv" "%_temp_folder%\temp_0.csv" /b

::: Set Pack number
set "_pack=01"

::: create "pack number" final agregated CSV file with proper headings
>"%_target_folder%\Pack_%_pack%.csv" echo.Date,Time

::: remove lines with headings from the temporary agregated CSV file created above
>"%_temp_folder%\temp_1.csv" findstr /v "Column1,Column2" "%_temp_folder%\temp_0.csv"

::: adds the data from temporary agregated CSV file to the final agregated CSV file
>>"%_target_folder%\Pack_%_pack%.csv" type "%_temp_folder%\temp_1.csv" 

REM ===============================================================================
REM TASK 3 - create list of csv files on Pack (only "main" files)
REM ===============================================================================

>>"%_target_folder%\Pack_%_pack%_LIST.txt" (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`type "%_temp_folder%\*source-file.csv"
        `) do echo/%%~na
   )
REM ===============================================================================
REM TASK 4 - create zip files (archive) of the selected files in TASK 1 ("main" + "flag" files)
REM ===============================================================================

"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe" a "%_target_folder%\Pack_%_pack%.rar" "%_temp_folder%\*source-file*.csv"

REM ===============================================================================
REM TASK 5 - delete files from temp folder // clean temporary files
REM ===============================================================================

del /q /a "%_temp_folder%\*.*"
```

the objective is on task #1, select files to reach a given total (Mb) size of files (like the example code above, for the folders) - so each created "pack_xx.csv" as approximately the same size.  And run it, until all files are "packed", unless the remaining files are less than a given total size.

Comment: Hi, thanks, explanation added

Comment: add a new explanation and the current code, hope more clear now.